# Error al ejecutar gnuplot con popen en C

Tags: c, gnuplot

estoy tratando de ejecutar gnuplot desde C para graficar funciones. Este es mi código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    fp = popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
    fprintf(fp, "plot sin(x)\n");
    fprintf(fp, "plot tan(x)\n");

    pclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Y el error que me aparece es en la ventana de comandos al ejecutar el programa:

"gnuplot" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: No encuentra el ejecutable `gnuplot`.

Comment: Y que es lo que sucede si solo colocas el comando, afuera del programa?

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, solo agregué mi programa ejecutable dentro de la carpeta de instalación de gnuplot.